# Javascript .on event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following scenario;  in my js I have a dynamic hyperlink that I need to capture the clicked link id.

```
for (var i = 0; i < neighbor.data[3].length; i++){
    <a class="Chris" name="a" id="+i+" href="Chris">Hi</a>
}
```

Now I can get this with;

```
    parseInt($(this).attr("ID"));
```

I am using this to capture the it;

```
$(document).on("click", "a.a", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert(clickedID);
    clickedID = parseInt($(this).attr("ID"));
});
```

Now, my problem is that everytime I click on the hyperlink instead of only one clickedID I have one for every hyperlink clicked. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on what's the expected behavior and what's the problem?

Comment: Why is your click handler using `"a.a"` when your elements have the class `"Chris"`? Also, why are you alerting the `clickedID` _before_ you set it? Your explanation of what you expect and what actually happens is a bit confusing - perhaps you could create a demo at http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: What is your for loop supposed to do? Are trying to `document.write` those anchor tags?

Comment: $('a.Chris').on('click', function(e){e.stopPropagation();alert($(this).id)});

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are getting every anchor tag because you are setting the event on the document, rather than the anchor tag. Try this instead:

```
$('a').on('click',function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  clickedID = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
  alert(clickedID);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your for loop.  Your `id="+i+"` will just set all anchor tags' IDs to `+i+` because you are not escaping the plus sign and the variable i

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, `"a.a"` should be `"a.Chris"` because `Chris` is the class name you have used not `a` and`id` should start with a non-numeric character.

```
for (var i = 0; i < neighbor.data[3].length; i++){
    var a='<a class="Chris" name="a" id="id_'+i+'" href="Chris">Hi</a>';
    $('#links').append(a);
}

$("#links").on("click", "a.Chris", function(event) { // You can use $(document).on(...) instead of $("#links").on(...)
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    clickedID = parseInt($(this).attr("id").split('_')[1]);
    alert(clickedID);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gDGfK/2/).